# Sql-Update Field only when null ELSE check next Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following code only updates a field when null for a given ID.

```
$sql="UPDATE TABLE7 set SCORE1= $high where SCORE1 IS NULL AND ID = 9";
```

How can I adjust the code so it updates a row only when null, and if not null, checks next row for a certain ID=9 etc. 
Something like:

```
$sql="UPDATE TABLE7 set
IF SCORE1 IS NULL THEN SCORE1= $high,
ELSE   //MEANING SCORE1 IS NOT NULL
IF SCORE2 IS NULL THEN SCORE2= $high,
ELSE   //  MEANING SCORE2 IS NOT NULL
IF SCORE3 IS NULL THEN SCORE3= $high
ELSE  //MEANING ALL FIELDS ARE NOT NULL
THROW ERROR (ECHO ‘All FIELDS ARE FILLED’)
WHERE ID = 9"
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

What I want is that after updating the first NULL field, other fields will not be updated.

ie if SCORE1 =NULL, then SCORE1 = $high but SCORE2 and SCORE3 shouldn't update, whether NULL or not.

I only want to update first NULL field ONLY. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE7 
set SCORE1 = case when SCORE1 IS NULL THEN $high else SCORE1 end,
    SCORE2 = case when SCORE2 IS NULL and SCORE1 is not null THEN $high else SCORE2 end,
    SCORE3 = case when SCORE3 IS NULL and SCORE1 is not null and score2 is not null THEN $high else SCORE3 end
WHERE ID = 9
and (score1 is null or score2 is null or score3 is null)
```

Comment: Nice work around. Your code updates ALL fields ie sets SCORE1 =$high, SCORE2=$high, SCORE3=$high.
What I wanted was that after updating the first NULL field, other fields will not be updated.
ie if SCORE1 =NULL, then SCORE1 = $high but SCORE2 and SCORE3 shouldn't update, whether NULL or not. 
I only want to update first NULL field ONLY. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: The add the other conditions as well. I updated my answer. I thought that was easy to adapt.